# ng-repeat $index to char in alphabet

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<script>var array_char = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g",..., "z"];</script>

<tr ng-repeat="r in myModel">
     <td>{{$index}}</td>
     <td>{{char in alphatbet?}}</td> 
</tr>
```

I want a, b, c... in column two. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read the following docs: [ng-repeat](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angRepeat), [controllers](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller), [application bootstrap](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap).

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="app">
    <table ng-controller="ctrl">
        <tr ng-repeat="r in myModel">
            <td>{{$index}}</td>
            <td>{{r}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

JS:

```
angular
.module("app", [])
.controller("ctrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.myModel = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "z"];
});
```

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/ImaLerOX/2/edit)